# How to optimize performance of COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) with a GROUP BY(exec_datetime)

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which shows the distinct ip addresses that made requests every day.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as ip_address, DATE(exec_datetime) as day
FROM requests
GROUP BY MONTH(exec_datetime), DAY(exec_datetime);
```

The output of `EXPLAIN` is the following

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  requests    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    472043  Using filesort
```

I don't have a clear understanding of covering indexes, because when I created one, the query took just as long to complete

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX unique_ip_per_time(ip_address, exec_datetime);
```

Here's the output of the `EXPLAIN`

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  requests    index   NULL    unique_ip_per_time  268 NULL    472043  Using index; Using filesort
```

How could I optimize this query either by creating an index or re-writing it?

**EDIT**

The execution time is about ~15 seconds for both statements (with and without the covering index).  The only other keys on this table are a `UNIQUE` surrogate and an `INDEX` on `ip_address`

`show indexes from requests`

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
requests    0   PRIMARY 1   request_id  A   386577  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
requests    1   ip_address  1   ip_address  A   193288  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
requests    1   unique_ip_per_time  1   ip_address  A   163 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
requests    1   unique_ip_per_time  2   exec_datetime   A   163 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

**EDIT 2**

I followed the instructions of eisberg, however this query takes about 1.1 seconds...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
  A.request_day,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.ip_address)
    FROM requests B
    WHERE B.exec_date = A.request_day
  ) as num_ip_addr
FROM request_days A
ORDER BY A.request_day ASC;
```

Which is slightly slower than this query which takes about .9 seconds

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as ip_address, exec_date
FROM requests
GROUP BY exec_date;
```

I don't think I need to create the additional table with the dates.  Are there any optimizations I can apply to part of the statement with `DISTINCT ip_address` (It seems to be the bottleneck)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a little workaround for this kind of problem. But you will need to put some work in it.

First of all you create an additional column on request to avoid extra calculations during your select:

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD COLUMN (request_day DATE);

ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX i1(request_day);

UPDATE requests SET request_day = DATE(exec_datetime);
```

Than you will need an extra table to memorize the days you can/want to select:

```
CREATE TABLE request_days (
  request_day DATE
);

ALTER TABLE request_days ADD UNIQUE INDEX i1(request_day);

INSERT IGNORE INTO request_days SELECT DATE(exec_datetime) FROM requests;
```

Finally you can:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
  A.request_day,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.ip_address)
    FROM requests B
    WHERE B.request_day = A.request_day
  )
FROM request_days A
ORDER BY A.request_day DESC
```

Which gives:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE         TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF                         ROWS    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY             A       index   (null)          i1  4       (null)                      1       Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  B       ref     i1              i1  4       db_2_95a42.A.request_day    1       Using where
```

I hope this will help you!

Example on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a42/2

Comment: Thanks for the innovative idea, I'll start digging into this now.  btw anything wrong with creating in index on `request_days` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: No I am just used to this way :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, by the way, is it worth it to create this index `ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX i1(request_day);`?  It's going to have pretty low cardinality, I'm getting about 10k records a day on the `requests` table

Comment: Without this index MySQL will have no key to join/sub-select on. So your performance will drop. If you want your data visible for each and every day you will need a key for each and every day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the DATE function on `exec_datetime`, the engine will scan all the rows of the table.
You should try `partitioning the table on exec_datetime` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Partitioning will only help if the user is about to select a subset of his data that is reflected in a smaller subset.

Comment: I don't think this would help since I would like to select all the data in every partition.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would simply need to add compound functional index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX month_day_idx
   ON requests (MONTH(exec_datetime), DAY(exec_datetime));
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support functional indexes. Instead, you have 2 choices:

1. Create extra columns for month and day and create compound index with those 2 new fields.
2. Or alter your GROUP BY to not use functions if you can.

Comment: The bottleneck isn't the `MONTH` and `DAY` functions, it's the `DISTINCT` function.  If I were to use functional indexes it would not be on `MONTH(exec_datetime)` and `DAY(exec_datetime)`.

Comment: I don't think so. By the way, having compound index `(MONTH(exec_datetime), DAY(exec_datetime), ip_address)` would be even better (if MySQL supported functional indexes), but you only have `(ip_address, exec_datetime)` - which is quite different and cannot be used by MySQL